# Allow Single Type Input in Html

Tags: html

Ok so i have a Chatroom, People are required to type in a name and once done they may chat. But alot of times people take other peoples name. So what i need is kind of like a limited input

here is the input:

```
<input type="text" class="input-block-level" ng-model="name" ng-change="setName()" placeholder="Your Name" maxlength="10" required></div>
```

I need this so if i type in the name Bob, no one can use that name again

Incase you want the website: https://project-js-imthatguy.c9users.io/

Comment: You aren't going to be able to do that with just HTML.

Comment: What does the function setName() do?

Comment: Are you storing the nicknames somewhere? If you do then there can be a solution

Comment: Like Scott said, HTML will not help you here. This requires a backend or 'server' function to manage connected users most likely using an array to store usernames. You need to provide much more information relative to your chat application for us to help.

Comment: As people mentioned, you will need more than just HTML, a backend/server would be best, but it looks like you are just starting out, so I would suggest creating something in the client side JS that checks their username just before submitting the message and sends an error message prompting the user to change their name

Comment: Ok so the setName() is being stored if you would look at the website, if you type in your name in the name slot everyone can see it and there is a list on the side that shows everyones name, the function is being called in a javascript, so yes if i need to use javascript thats ok, Jarod could you show how to do that in js, i use html most and barely use js so i have no idea

Comment: Also im glad everyone is having fun on the chat haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way to check amongst a given set...

used a simple for loop for this example

Inside your send function that you have defined, perform a check:

```
    $scope.send = function send() {
      var isDuplicated = 0
      for (i = 0; i < $scope.roster.length; i++){
        if ($scope.roster[i] == $scope.name){ isDuplicated++ }
      }
      if (isDuplicated > 1){
        //make an error message appear here
        //quick and dirty solution
        alert('Please choose a name that has not been taken by someone else')
        //suggestion set a variable here to true and then use that variable to show/hide a div below the user input area
      }
      else {
        console.log('Sending message:', $scope.text);
        socket.emit('message', $scope.text);
        $scope.text = '';
     }
    };
```

Comment: this is js, correct so i will need to reference this in my html if that is correct, in the send button or the name input slot should i enter this reference of send()

Comment: I just copied your send function and added some things to it, so if you take this send function and replace yours it might work, I am not able to test it...